# How to send data parameter on leaflet-ajax

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ajax

i have a problem about sending data parameter to leaflet ajax,
i'm using https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax
anyone know how to send data parameter ? i have reading documentation but did't get it if i using https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax

here's my code:

```
function popUp(f,l){
var out = [];
if (f.properties){
    for(key in f.properties){
        out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
    }
    l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
}}
var myurl = "127.0.0.1/data.json";
var jsonTest = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(myurl,{onEachFeature:popUp}).addTo(m);
```

Comment: I would suggest rather than making a L.GeoJSON.AJAX call for each feature and then executing the popup code, a better approach would be to get all your geojson in one ajax call then process the geojson for each popup.

Comment: i can't do that, because so many data will loaded.

Comment: how may features are you talking about, 1000, 10,000, a 1000,000?

Comment: more than 100.000 and will grow up.

Comment: Ok. Any possibility you can get your data into a postgis table and then use another ajax method and query by attribute? In my experience geojson and +100,000 points do not play well together.